# Storing mail server data on multiple storage servers

Tags: centos, email-server, cloud-storage

I'm trying to provide an email service for my clients

And i like to know is it possible to store mail-server data on different servers
Something like cloud services

I'm a beginner , And i have installed CPanel on my CentOS server
Let's call it front-server

I can create email accounts on my front-server with a php script and CPanel XML Api
But i like to configure this server to store email datas on some additional servers
Like storage server1 , Storage server 2 and ...

Thank you all

Comment: user2249101, welcome to Server Fault. but this question may get closed soon.  If it does, please don't take it personally.  The problem is that it's an extremely open-ended question about a complex setup, but at the same time you're using cpanel; the former makes us think you need an experienced sysadmin, and the latter makes us suspect you might not be one.  If those are both true, this question can't be answered with less than a small book - and that makes it unsuitable for SF.  You might want to read our FAQ before posting again.

Comment: Thank you for the advise , I won't get it personally , And i'm respecting to SF rules :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPanel is an integrated "fire-and-forget" tool for basic web hosting needs. If you aim fo redundancy or distribution of services, CPanel is not for you.

On the IMAP/POP3 server software side, multiple solutions to get redundancy in mail storage do exist, the most elegant probably being [Dovecot with a mailstore on a distributed file system](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/SharedDisk). But redundancy and high availability in general and a redundant mail storage in particular is not a beginner's topic since it needs some experience to be able to model the impact of configuration changes on your infrastructure's resilience. You certainly would need a couple of months in a lab environment testing possible configurations and failure modes before you get such a setup more or less "right".

Comment: Hi , Thank you for your great answer , Actually i'm trying to learn already , But i don't have enough time at this moment , I see CPanel can work with Dovecot mail server , Can i use it right now and after some time manage it manually ? Or setup my own server and transfer old email datas on it ?

Comment: @user2249101 surely you *can* start with a cpanel install and migrate later on. I would not advise using a cpanel-configured Dovecot for manual management - too many things can break or behave unpredictably.